# Resize JPanel based on component inside it

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable inside a JPanel. Maximum number of rows in table is 10. Based on the table rows I need to resize the JPanel. I should not get any scrollPane.

So, to be simple: based on the table size I should resize the panel. Is this possible?

Comment: should be poosible. Just get the table size with its attributes and set the jpanel according to it..

Comment: Table won't load when the Jpanel is Loading. User will browse and select files.while the panel is loading there wont be any Table. We will add the table only if user Browse and add a file.

Comment: that's the task for a LayoutManager - read the corresponding chapter in the tutorial referenced in the swing tag

Comment: @CyrillC - no, you never-ever set a size (nor a location) manually ...

Comment: @kleopatra I would argue that point, but ONLY if you have a really, really good reason to do so (should you manually set the bounds of a componet) - JLayeredPane comes to mind

Comment: @MadProgrammer the approximation of _never-ever_ is good enough not only for a newby :-) Obviously, there is always the odd corner case of ppb probability which requires breaking a rule .. btw, there is nothing in the JLayeredPane that _excludes_ using a suitable manager, only none of core can handle z-order.

Comment: @kleopatra I couldn't agree more, I did a nice multi table, grouped column component, with multiple tables and multiple row columns using nothing more then a flow and grid layout, works wonderfully, I've also done a complex "light box" component, requiring a complex layout routine, I just get narky @ "never", cause there's always someone breaking the rules ;) - besides, I'm to lazy not to try and make sure I've exhausted all the layout possibilities

Answer (score 1):

I believe `jtable.getPreferredSize()` should return a reasonable result. If tat fails, you could use the tables font metrics and the tabes default row height to estimate the size.

Comment: no need for font metrics, rowheight is what you are after (works with and without data).

Comment: *smacks head*, yes, your right, it should be rowHeight & rowCount +1 fir keeping me in my toes (also +1 for your open mindedness)

Answer (score 1):

1.in this case is `GridBagLayout` best of standard `LayoutManagers` for `JTable` placed to the `JPanel` and without using `JScrollPane`

2.notice `JTable` by default doesn't supporting resize of rows on `vertical direction`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class TableAndGbc {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JTable table = new JTable(10, 10);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        panel.add(table, gbc);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```